Motorcycle's gears won't engage from an off state
I have a 2009 Honda CBF600SA motorcycle, and the motorcycle's gears work well when I'm riding the motorcycle or generally while it is "on".
However when I turn the motorcycle off and leave it, if I try to start the motorcycle again, the starter will most of the time be unable to engage the engine and it won't start. At this time if I try to engage the first gear using clutch and downpedal, that will also fail: I just can't push the pedal down to engage the gear.
However, if I move the motorcycle a little bit back or forward, then I can engage the first gear, and I can also start just fine.
What might be going on? Any thoughts on what to check and how to resolve this?

Is there a kick stand switch preventing starts when its down? Is there a Neutral start safety switch preventing starts? Is the clutch worn, creating intermittent gear shifting with engine off? It's more or less normal when unable to shift to move the bike forward or back a little to allow shifts when the clutch wears down.

There is a kick stand switch but that's not the issue, since I can't even engage the gear and I'm sure the kick stand is up. If the kickstand is down, the start won't even trigger, whereas in my case the starter motor tries to engage the engine but fails.

AFAIK there is no Neutral Start Safety Switch either, given the circumstances I almost always shift into first gear, hold the clutch and start the bike.

I would be extra cautious about starting in gear, even with the clutch out since you have no way of knowing when a clutch wears down and still partially engaged; the starter will turnover the engine and while in gear from a worn clutch, will lurch. It's wise to always start in neutral, worn clutch or not. Cars, trucks and suvs cannot start unless in Park or Neutral. Manuals require holding the clutch pedal down to start with most drivers, I presume, leaving the xmission in neutral.

I finally figured this out, and it turned out to be simpler than I thought:
The clutch lever was not adjusted properly, so it was not ever fully engaging the clutch, thus never fully disengaging the gears, even when I pulled the clutch lever all the way in, this was somehow causing the issue with the gears not being properly engaged when trying to start the motorbike after a stop. After adjusting the clutch lever's free-play and ensuring that I have complete disengagement of gears by pulling the lever in about 80-90% of the way, I stopped having any issues with starting the bike and my gear shifting is a lot smoother as well.
TL;DR; adjusting clutch lever free play fixed it.


Well for starters, you have two separate symptoms, that may or may not be related. I’m leaning more to not related. If you raise the rear tire off the ground and spin it by hand (wear a glove in case there’s debris in there that could cut you) with the engine off and someone holding the clutch lever in, see if you can feel it go through all six gears. It shouldn’t let you go past first, and it shouldn’t let you go past sixth. This will tell us that at least the shift drum is behaving. If it were me, I like to just take the motor out and split the case open and look. If the clutch and shifter have adjustments and they are correct, then it’s going to have to come apart to fix anyway. Guessing from the outside is purely trivia/academic.
Having said that, the “answer” to you question are typical and what you may have already heard. Worn bearings anywhere from the clutch basket to the output sprocket. Worn shift drum or forks. Worn shifter shaft or pawls. Any of those things can be bent also, except for the bearings.
Add the year to your question also please.

Thanks for the insight! I'll probably end up opening the case and diagnosing it closely.

Can you please explain a bit more what do you mean by "it shouldn't let you go past first and it shouldn't let you go past sixth" when moving the rear wheel?

Your motorcycle has a side stand switch, a clutch switch and a neutral switch. Check if any of these or any wiring failing (also intermittently) would explain the starting issue.
These are the conditions under which the engine can/cannot run:

This motorcycle is equipped with a side stand
ignition cut-off system. The engine cannot be
started if the side stand is down, unless the
transmission is in neutral. If the side stand is
up, the engine can be started in neutral or in
gear with the clutch lever pulled in. After
starting with the side stand down, the engine
will shut off if the transmission is put in gear
before raising the side stand.

Regarding shifting into first gear:

At this time if I try to engage the first gear using clutch and downpedal, that will also fail: I just can't push the pedal down to engage the gear.

Is the gearshift lever entirely blocked or does it move a bit but not far enough to engage first gear?
The latter is not something I would be concerned about.
Below picture shows the countershaft parts of a Honda 2005 CBF600SA (PC38) transmission which should be fairly similar to your motorcycle. Engaging a gear means engaging two parts like the highlighted ones. With everything stationary, there are positions where the dogs are not aligned with the dog holes and the gear cannot be engaged. Either the mainshaft or the countershaft need to rotate a bit. Moving the motorcycle rotates the countershaft, engine running rotates the mainshaft (even with clutch pulled).

I would recommend ruling out electric issues before getting to any major disassembly.

Thanks for the explanations. Regarding "The latter is not something I would be concerned about.", my concern is that this is the only motorcycle which has this issue, how come my other motorcycles never had this issue if this is normal?

There are different designs of transmissions. We don't know what kind of transmission your other motorcycles had.

@mahdi I had a similar issue on a bike of a different make. It didn't take a big roll to fix it, usually just rocking in place was enough. It's somewhat normal.
